# Maven: including utils in Java project

Tags: java, maven, jar, class-library

The case is quite simple, but I still can't solve it:

**INFO**: All 'projects' I am talking about are Maven projects.

I have certain Java project that I am working on right now. Recently, I have written a lot of general-purpose code in this project. I also have an 'utils' project with some Java utils in it, so I decided to move the general-purpose code from my main project (let's call it 'A') to the utils project. This would be practical because:

1. I have less clutter in A
2. I can reuse the code in other projects without bringing the unrelated content of 'A' in scope.

The problem is that utils is, of course, an utility project, a library if you want. And it does not have a main class. When I try to install (`mvn install`) it, no sources are included because there is no proper entry point.

So, after trying a lot of things, I have the concern that I am approaching this problem completely wrong and that's why I came here. I do not have any experience with Maven except the simple use case (e.g. including external libraries from Maven Central). Therefore my question is:

Which steps are required to make my utils library available in project 'A'?

I am not aiming to install my project on Maven Central or any other remote repository. I just want it available in my local mvnrepo. I am aware that this means that I'll have to clone my utils project and install it everywhere where I try to use project 'A'.

**EDIT 1**: I am using Java 11 (openjdk11), Maven 3.6.0, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with Maven Helper plugin and also GitHub in order to make my projects available anywhere.

Also, I have just checked that project 'A' correctly includes the jar from the utils project and actually adds it to the classpath (but the jar is empty). So, the problem really seems to be in the utils project.

Answer (score 0):

A maven `install` would place your compiled code in the local maven repository (.m2/repository).

[Sources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) are packaged by the source plugin.

```
mvn source:jar
```

Comment: As I have already pointed out, `mvn install` produces an empty jar. And as far as I am concerned, the sources packaging is only needed for deeper insight in the code (e.g. when debugging). Please correct me if that is wrong

Comment: mvn install should not give an empty jar when there is a flled `src/main/java/`. After seeing you use a modular java, module-info in the root must export the classes. Maybe start with a sample maven project first.

Comment: currently, the utils project is designed to contain utils for more languages than just java. This is why the source root (marked as 'source root' in IntelliJ) is src/main/code and the Java root is actually src/main/code/com.tara.util.java. If this is actually the problem, I could probably find a workaround but I am not sure if Maven really requires the sources to be in src/main/java

Comment: It is configurable in maven; do not know how, as I am not ---.